# Add date of last row update in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a table with `3` columns and multiple rows. One of the column is *last-edited-date* where I want to display date when any cell in a row was last time updated.

Now I manually change cell with the date, but I'm looking for an automatic solution instead.

How can we do this with Excel? I didn't find any *native* way?

Answer (score 0):

Answering myself. It is possible with simple VBE code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.EnableEvents = False
    Cells(Target.Row, "P").Value = Date
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

- In Excel go to *right-click* on spreadsheet name (usually bottom left) and then select *View code...*
- Paste above code in new window
- Save and close

That's it. Now every time cell in a row is changed, column `P` (in my case) is set with current date. Change letter to your column to use different one.